# How to make a command that adds a role to a user

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm not sure on how to make a command in Discord.js that adds a mentioned user to a role.
Eg: `?addrole @JustProGaming#1785 @Owner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this: whenever the `addrole` command is called, assign to every mentioned member every mentioned role. This structure is pretty good because it works no matter the order of the arguments.

```
// 'message' is the message that triggered the command
if (command == 'addrole') {
  let members = message.mentions.members,
    roles = message.mentions.roles;

  if (!members.size) return message.reply("You didn't mention any member!");
  if (!roles.size) return message.reply("You didn't mention any role!");

  members.forEach(member => member.addRoles(roles, `Command issued by ${message.author.tag}`));
}
```